# Laravel 5.5 email setup using Mailgun and Bogardo

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I am attempting to setup automated email notification in my Laravel 5.5 app using Mailgun. I have the Mailgun SDK installed along with the recommended Laravel library - Bogardo. The reason I am using the Bogardo library instead of just using the Mailgun SDK or built in Laravel email functionality is neither of these allow for click tracking, bounces and other analytic functionality (that I know of). I am able to send emails just fine using Tinker. However, I am not 100% sure how to properly call my new mailable to send an email that way. Here is my mailable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BaseEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        $data = ['This is a message from Mailgun!'];

        return Mailgun::raw($data, function($message) {
            $message
                ->to('email@domain.com', 'Name Name')
                ->subject('Yoohoo!')
                ->from('otheremail@domain.com', 'Name')
                ->tag(['tag','tag2']);
        });
    }
}
```

When I call:

```
$mail = new App\Mail\BaseEmail();
$mail->send();
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Mail\Mailable::send(), 0 passed in /web/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ExecutionLoop/Loop.php(90) : eval()'d code on line 1 and exactly 1 expected
```

and

```
$mail->send('this');
```

I get

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailable::send() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer, string given on line 1
```

Sorry if this is trivial, but I have been following their docs and have Googled everything that I can think of with no luck.

Any direction would be fantastic!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Bogardo package does not support Laravel Mailables...

https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `send()` method when you're using `raw()`.This code will send an email:

```
Mailgun::raw($data, function($message) {
    $message->to('email@domain.com', 'Name Name')
            ->subject('Yoohoo!')
            ->from('otheremail@domain.com', 'Name')
            ->tag(['tag','tag2']);
});
```

You also don't need to use `Mailable` when you're using the package.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I understand that the above code will send an email, I have verified that using Tinker. What I want to do it call my mailable class BaseEmail and send the email. I believe that is the way to do it? Thanks again!